# How do I find out the total number of items in a collection? mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 100 items in the collection, each item has a "money" field, I need to get the total amount of money from all, preferably without crutches. i don't know how to did it.

```
const allMoney = async () => {
    let count = 0;
    await User.find({}).sort({ money: -1 }).forEach(plr => { count+=plr.money });
    return count;
}
```

"user is my model"

Comment: forEach will not return anything you should use reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Mongoose [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) with the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and
[$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operators, just like this:

```
user.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: { $sum: "$money" }
    }
  }
])
```

The **_id: null** expression is necessary because a group specification must include it obligatorily. Otherwise Mongoose will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate with a group which will easily fetch the total amount for you.

Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/
for more clarification.

```
const allMoney = async () => {
    var aggregate = Scheme.aggregate()
    aggregate.group({
      _id: null,
      totalMoney: {$sum: '$money'}
    )}
    aggregate.exec(function(err, result) {
      if (err) return err;
      return result;
    });
}
```